# In PowerShell how to copy files from a Remote PSsession to another Windows server

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to copy a folder from one remote server to another inside a PSSession, it's giving errors like access is denied. I have admin privileges to both of the servers. If I try it without PSSession it works.

In remote serverA

```
PS C:\Users\Automation\Documents> [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
sql
PS C:\Users\Automation\Documents> Copy-Item -Path .\abc.csv -Destination "\\jump\c$"
PS C:\Users\Automation\Documents>
```

In remote serverB

```
    PS C:\Users\Automation\Documents\sample\SQL Final Scripts> Copy-Item -Path ".\SQL_queries.csv" -Destination "\\sql\c$\"
    PS C:\Users\Automation\Documents\sample\SQL Final Scripts> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName sql  -Credential "automation@lab"

    [sql]: PS C:\Users\Automation\Documents> Copy-Item -Path ".\SQL_queries.csv" -Destination "\\jump\c$\"


Copy-Item : Access to the path '\\jump\c$\' is denied.
        + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\Automa...SQL_queries.csv:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], Unauthorized
       AccessException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand


    [sql]: PS C:\Users\Automation\Documents>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are facing the "Double Hop" problem. Run this on the SQL computer

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
```

and run this on Server B

```
Enable-WSManCred -Role Client -DelegateComputer *
```

then when you enter the remote session do

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName sql -Authentication Credssp -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Hope this helps.

If you sneezed during reading this answer, Bless your face.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are facing the "double hop" problem, which is solved by using [CredSSP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/06/05/credssp-for-second-hop-remoting-part-i-domain-account.aspx)

Comment: You are facing the "Double Hop" problem. Run this on the SQL computer `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server` and run this on Server B `Enable-WSManCred -Role Client -DelegateComputer *` then when you enter the remote session do `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName sql -Authentication Credssp -Credential (Get-Credential)`

Comment: @BobLobLaw, if you post that as an answer instead of a comment on mine, it'll stand a chance at being accepted as the superior answer (over mine).