# Powershell: Remote install fails when trying to connect to database

Tags: powershell, oracle11g, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access, powershell-remoting

I have been struggling for a few days with this issue. I tried googling the issue but haven't found any answers.

I am trying to install an exe on a remote machine (VM) using powershell. The application uses oracle and mysql to check the connection to a database while installing. My Powershell script copies the install files to the remote machine. Then connects to the machine and runs the exe. It works until it checks the database connection.

When I use Remote Desktop Connection and connect to the remote machine I can run the exe and it successfully checks the database connection and completes the install. 
I can even connect from the VM to my Box using powershell and it installs correctly.

I'm assuming it has to do with the remote machines permissions but I'm not sure. Does anyone have any ideas why the installer can't connect and how to fix the issue?

**The machine specs, script and exceptions are below.**

My Box is running **Windows 7 Professional SP1 x64**

**Oracle Version:** 11.2.0

The VM is running **Windows Server 2008 R2 x64**

**Oracle Version:** 11.2.0

```
#Copies required install files and file passed in as an argument to remote machine
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination \\$computer\$destination\Install -Recurse -Force
Copy-Item -Path C:\$argument -Destination \\$computer\$destination -Recurse -Force

#Connect to remote machine
Enter-Pssession $computerIP -credential $cred

#Starts the install
(Start-Process -FilePath C:\Setup.exe -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
```

The log returns **errorcode** -2147467259

**The Exception:**

*at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()*

No innerexception is returned.

Comment: Is the application authenticating to Oracle using Windows Integrated authentication?  If so, you are probably experiencing the so-called 'double-hop' authentication issue - [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15539931/64028) for help on working around it using CredSSP.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Not exactly. I know it had to do with permissions on the VM I was trying to access. However, I ended up trying the installation on another VM and it worked.