# Powershell remote install .exe file errors and not finding setup.iss file

Tags: networking, powershell, powershell-2.0, remote-access, invoke-command

Hi I am trying to figure out how to install .exe files to 5 server machine but I am having trouble trying to install silently on my own machine.
I have this command
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath \\xxx-STUDENT3-W7\Users\bkoo004\Documents\test\ccleaner402.exe \r}
but I can't find the setup.iss file in the Windows folder.
Also when I use this command

Invoke-Command -computername xxxxxxxxxxx.edu -ScriptBlock {start-process -filepath "\\xxx-S
TUDENT3-W7\Users\bkoo004\Documents\test\ccleaner402.exe" } -Credential $cred

It gives me an error saying that
This command cannot be executed due to the error: The network name cannot be found.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

But I know that network name is right because when I run
 Invoke-Command -computername xxxxxxxxxxx.edu -ScriptBlock {get-process } -Credential $cred
It returns the get-process of that server.

I figured that for not getting the setup.iss file it is because the program that i am trying to install doesn't use installshield but for the error trying to run start-process on my remote server I have no idea what it is.

Comment: If you're going to use any remote commands that have a network location you need to fix the [double-hop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx) problem.

Comment: New-PSSession xxxxxxxxxx.edu -authentication CredSSP -credential $cred | Invoke-Command -computername xxxxxxxxxxxx.edu -ScriptBlock {start-process -filepath "\\xxx-STUDENT3-W7\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\test\S
etup.exe" }                using that command I still get network not found error

Comment: Also I don't get how what I am trying to do causes double hop problem? I am not trying to make my server access remotely to anywhere. Sorry I am really noob in this area

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are running into the double-hop problem on not, but it sounds like you are. So I though I'd give you a little more information about it. The Bob Loblaw version.

What is a server and what is a client? A server, it accepts things, is the computer you remote onto. A client, it gives things, is the computer you use to do the remoting. So in the command `Invoke-Command -computername xxxxxxxxxxx.edu ...`, "xxxxxxxxxxx.edu" is the server.

From your description, it looks like you already ran the command `Enable-PSRemoting` on your server. With remoting enabled on the server you should be able to do `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName xxxxxxxxxxx.edu` and have an interactive command prompt on the client.

If you enter a remote session and do `Get-ChildItem "\\ComputerName\Share"` the command is going to fail (it fails for safety reasons). That's the double-hop, because you're going from one computer to another. The network share is another computer. So you're going like this:

> Client -> Server -> Network Share

[Hippity-Hoppity](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iea1wmYV0Lc)

You need to setup more ["things"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501241/in-powershell-how-to-copy-files-from-a-remote-pssession-to-another-windows-serve/15539931#15539931) to fix the double-hop. First on your server(s) you need to run the command `Enable-WSManCredSSP Server` so it will accept credentials from clients. Second on your client(s) you need to run the command `Enable-WSManCred -Role Client -DelegateComputer *` so it gives out your credential to servers.

Now with CredSSP configured to give and accept credentials, you should have resolved the doulbe-hop.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Computer1 -Authentication Credssp -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Now you should be able to get to your network shares from the remote session `Get-ChildItem "\\ComputerName\Share"`.

Hope this helps you out a bit.

P.S. There is always money in the banana stand.

Comment: When I use this command 
Invoke-Command -computername xxx-fs-2.ads.xxx.edu -authentication credssp -credential $cred -ScriptBlock {start-process -filepath "\\xxx-fs-1.xxx.ucr.edu\software\npp.6.3.3.Installer.exe" -argumentlist "/S" } 

My powershell just hangs. My guess is that there is a security warning check to open .exe file. How can I bypass this?

Comment: So does that mean you got the double-hop issue fixed?

Comment: The next thing I would test is enter an interactive session, using `Enter-PSSession` and see if `\\Computer\Share\NPP.exe /S` will install. If that don't work you might have better luck asking another question. I'm not a pro on remote installations. I don't know if the installation getting stuck would have to do with UAC or not. But I do believe when you run an installation file the prompt will only return once the installation is finished, it think.

Comment: When I used Enter-pssession and try to install it I get access denied error if i do not use credssp and I get requires elevation error if I use credssp..

Comment: if I use this command after enter-pssession my powershell just hangs

Comment: Start-Process -FilePath \\xxx-fs-1.ads.xxx.edu\software\npp.6.3.3
.Installer.exe -ArgumentList "/S"                                                              and I am running this command after running                                     Enter-PSSession -authentication credssp -credential $cred -ComputerName xxx-fs-2.ads.xxx.edu